# MiKTeX not compiling

Tags: errors, miktex, compiling

MiKTeX stopped compiling. Originally it was only pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX that wasn't working, pdfLaTeX worked just fine. I tried a complete reinstall and now nothing works (including LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX).

Here are the logs.

```
2020-07-13 22:59:00,273-0400 ERROR texify.core - Function: CopyFileW
2020-07-13 22:59:00,273-0400 ERROR texify.core - Result: 5
2020-07-13 22:59:00,273-0400 ERROR texify.core - Data: existing="C:/Users/Jason/AppData/Local/Temp/mik18554/_src\untitled-2.pdf", path="C:/Users/Jason/Documents/Notes\untitled-2.pdf"
2020-07-13 22:59:00,273-0400 ERROR texify.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp:383
2020-07-13 22:59:00,288-0400 FATAL texify - Windows API error 5: Access is denied.

2020-07-13 22:59:00,288-0400 FATAL texify - Info: existing="C:/Users/Jason/AppData/Local/Temp/mik18554/_src\untitled-2.pdf", path="C:/Users/Jason/Documents/Notes\untitled-2.pdf"
2020-07-13 22:59:00,288-0400 FATAL texify - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2020-07-13 22:59:00,288-0400 FATAL texify - Line: 383
```

Running pdflatex through command line gives the following:

```
C:\Users\Jason\Documents>pdflatex main.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6.29)
entering extended mode
(main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>
(C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size11.clo))
(C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty)
(C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdf
mode.def) (main.aux)
! I can't write on file `main.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output:
```

Running the command `latex main.tex` produces a DVI file just fine.

Comment: Well your log says only "Access is denied". That doesn't give much clues. Create a small tex document, close everything miktex related, then try to compile this document on a command line. Perhaps this gives more clues whats wrong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i ran a dummy doc through cmd, a dvi is produced just fine however trying to generate a pdf fails. more or less same logs

Comment: did you try with pdflatex alone? what exactly does it says on the command line?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer see edits to the post

Comment: what happens if you do `pdflatex --jobname=somethingspecial main`?

Comment: same thing happens, a blank text document and an aux file called somethingspecial are created

Comment: in the miktex issue tracker someone had a problem because the antivirus software prevented the writing of the pdf (or something else), see https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/585

Comment: Ah yes it was Avast that was causing the issue... goddamn it. Thank you so much for your help.