# Texmaker/MiKTeX not creating PDF file

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texmaker

After installing an update on Windows 10, Texmaker is no longer compiling or showing the PDF file. I read the solutions provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553464/miktex-not-compiling) and [here](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/585), but these are not my situation. I do not have avast and when I run the command `pdflatex test.tex` in the command window, the PDF file is created. I already tried reinstalling MiKTeX and Texmaker.

Update: I am not sure if this happened with the update, but I was clicking on the Run icon with the LaTeX and not Quick Build or PDFLaTeX. Since I hadn't chance anything, I kept clicking on it, assuming it wasn't going to be a problem. I noticed this because with F1, the pdf is created.

Comment: Hi and welcome. What antivirus do you have?

Comment: thanks. I have McAfee

Comment: do you get any error message from texmaker?

Comment: @oxj Disable your antivirus, this will enable the native `Windows Defender` antivirus which is just as effective (and yes, they have made progress), read: https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-windows/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer no errors in the log file

Comment: @AndréC already uninstalled, it did not help.

Comment: Show the log-file of a small, failing example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  I found the error. After the updates, when I reopened texmaker I had the LaTex option next to the Run icon (I did not change it). Once changed to Quick Build or  PDFLaTeX, the problem was fixed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is solved as indicated in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if it would help anyone. But this is what worked for me.

- uninstalling McAfee
- reinstalling MikTeX and Texmaker across all users in my PC. MikTeX needed some updates.
- making sure "...\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64" was added to my path
- verifying I had pdflatex, and if so its location
- lastly, it might be silly, double checking when you click on the Run icon, next to it you have Quick Build option or PDFLaTeX.